# Queso fresco / queso latino is raw food?

Tags: cheese, raw

In Spain, you can find "Queso latino" in the supermarkets (at least in DIA). It comes in sealed plastic bags as it contains a lot of water and quite soft. I understand that in other locations it's name might be "queso fresco". I've found here some photos of the product and it's varieties [here](http://www.quesoslatinos.com/catalogo-online).

My question is, if this variety cheese can be considered raw food.

I think that a good definition of raw food cheese is that it's made of unpasteurized milk and it's not heated above or 40°C

Answer (score 3):

In order to separate the curd from the whey, the milk is heated to a boil, so no, I would not consider this a raw food based on the definition you have in parenthesis.

Edit: In response to the clarified definition of raw food cheese, I would still say queso fresco does not qualify since the milk is heated well above the 40 degrees Celsius in the process of making it. I believe you can use either pasteurized or unpasteurized milk to make it. It's very similar (almost identical) to Indian paneer.